# Jasper server portlet with liferay integration

Tags: liferay, jasperserver

Environment:

1. JasperReportsServer-portlet-5.0.1 war deployed in LIferay 6.1.20 -----No errors. Successfully deployed.
2. Jasper server (5.1) is also running.

3.Also made change to portlet.xml to give jasper server's URL.

4.provided the trusted ip in pplicationContext-security-web.xml

Q1: But when i tried to display this default jasper server portlet to page i am getting error as

> ```
> Connection Refused
> The portal cannot connect to JasperReportsServer. Please contact your JasperReportsServer administrator.
> ```

When i tried to add the report using reports admin (control panel) its getting published.No error.

Q2 let me know is there any trust issues between jasper and liferay?

Q3: compatibility between liferay 6.1.30 and jasper server 5.1? are they compatible.?Which 
portlet file i need to use?

Can any one suggest me the solution...

Comment: If possible ,please share some doc and portlet link..

Answer (score 0):

there should be jasper-web plugin war for your liferay version.. for your report admin portlet to work it will required this jasper-web war deployed.

Comment: I am not sure if you require JasperReportsServer-portlet-5.0 ? Is there any error in console ?

Comment: there is no error..I also tried jasper EE portlet ..it is working partially